# cURL GET query string is a JSON

Tags: json, http, curl

I am try to access the remote RESTful Services API using cURL, the query string parameter has a JSON value. My cURL command like:

```
curl -g -i 'http://localhost:8080/context/restdev/employees/?q={"deptno":{"$lte":20}}'
```

If I enter the URL in the Chrome, I can get the data back. My cURL command gets: The URI is not well-formed, reason: Illegal character in query at position: 48

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your query

```
q={"deptno":{"$lte":20}}'
```

needs to be [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  cURL supports that with the --data-urlencode switch, so try this (one line):

```
curl -G -i "http://localhost:8080/context/restdev/employees/" 
--data-urlencode 'q={"deptno":{"$lte":20}}'
```

Comment: Working fine now after adding a -G option to use the GET method